# How to control image size in div id by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my style

```
#frame {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#frame img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I need to control "#frame img" with JavaScript.

(note: I don't want to give "#frame img" a new name id)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are looking for `querySelectorAll`:

```
var myElement = document.querySelectorAll('#frame img');
```

Size? You can control the `style`: `myElement.style.width = ...`.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct and send them an up vote if the answer solved your problem... not only does it help others who find your question, but it sends the person who answered points.